# linear layout is not centerted vertically in its parent when its sibling linear layout is gone

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, gravity, android-layout-weight

I have this xml

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="@color/google_blue900"
        android:orientation="vertical">
      <LinearLayout
          android:id="@+id/display_name_layout"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="0dp"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:gravity="center_vertical"
          android:background="@color/google_red100"
          android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/account_display_name"
            style="@style/AccountDataDisplayName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/google_green50"
            tools:text="DisplayNameIsLongSoItShouldBeTruncatedAtSomePoint"/>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/display_name_chevron"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/account_menu_chevron_size"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/account_menu_chevron_size"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/account_menu_chevron_top_margin"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/account_menu_chevron_left_margin"/>
      </LinearLayout>
      <LinearLayout
          android:id="@+id/account_name_layout"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="0dp"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:gravity="center_vertical"
          android:background="@color/google_blue50"
          android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/account_name"
            style="@style/AccountDataAccountName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:background="@color/google_yellow50"
            tools:text="emailisverylongaswellwewantittogettruncated@gmail.longdomain.com"/>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/account_name_chevron"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/account_menu_chevron_size"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/account_menu_chevron_size"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/account_menu_chevron_top_margin"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/account_menu_chevron_left_margin"/>
      </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

when i change the visibility of the second linear layout to be gone,

I expect the upper linear layout to be center vertical in it's linear layout parent.

what am i missing as now it's not centered vertically

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use `invisible` instead of `gone`. That will solve the problem. What `gone` do is it removes the layout entirely and in result the layout alignment goes out, while using `invisible` just turn in invisible.

Comment: but i don't want to calculate non-visible layout. what do you mean `alignment goes out`? it should put the only one layout vertically centered. why not? what's the base for you assumption?